Glass transparency not exporting to image
I'm trying to export a rendered image from Blender. When I see the finished render in the viewport, it looks great! Exactly what I wanted. However, then I export this render to an image, and that image loses all those pretty reflections that are necessary to indicate the presence of the glass to begin with.
I do have Transparent and Transparent Glass both checked off under the film section of the render settings. Playing with the image in Gimp shows that the reflections ARE there, but are so faint in the exported version that they can't be seen. Exporting as EXR is a little better, but the reflections are still way more faint than they should be. I also tried the custom composite nodes suggested at the following link, and that didn't fix the issue either.
Transparent emissive objects glow effect not visible in rendered output files
What is going on here, and how can I fix it?
In Blender:

In external image programs after export:


This question is similar to: Transparent emissive objects glow effect not visible in rendered output files. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
